# KL-Divergence of Uniform distributions

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Having $P=Unif[0,\theta_1]$ and  $Q=Unif[0,\theta_2]$ where $0<\theta_1<\theta_2$

I would like to calculate the KL divergence $KL(P,Q)=?$

I know the uniform pdf: $\frac{1}{b-a}$ and that the distribution is continous, therefore I use the general KL divergence formula:
$$KL(P,Q)=\int f_{\theta}(x)*ln(\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{f_{\theta^*}(x)})$$
$$=\int\frac{1}{\theta_1}*ln(\frac{\frac{1}{\theta_1}}{\frac{1}{\theta_2}})$$
$$=\int\frac{1}{\theta_1}*ln(\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_1})$$

From here on I am not sure how to use the integral to get to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it almost right, but you forgot the indicator functions. So the pdf for each uniform is
$$P(P=x) = \frac{1}{\theta_1}\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}(x)$$
$$\mathbb P(Q=x) = \frac{1}{\theta_2}\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]}(x)$$

Hence,
$$
KL(P,Q) = \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{\theta_1}\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}(x)
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}}{\theta_1 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]}}\right)dx
$$

Since $\theta_1 < \theta_2$, we can change the integration limits from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,\theta_1]$ and eliminate the indicator functions from the equation. Also, since the distribution is constant, the integral can be trivially solved
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{\theta_1}\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}}{\theta_1 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]}}\right)dx =
\int_{\mathbb [0,\theta_1]}\frac{1}{\theta_1}
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_1}\right)dx=$$
$$
=\frac {\theta_1}{\theta_1}\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_1}\right) -
\frac {0}{\theta_1}\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_1}\right)=
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_2}{\theta_1}\right)
$$
And you are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot Davi Barreira, I see the steps now.

Looking at the alternative, $KL(Q,P)$, I would assume the same setup:

$$
\int_{\mathbb [0,\theta_2]}\frac{1}{\theta_2}
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right)dx=$$
$$
=\frac {\theta_2}{\theta_2}\ln\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right) -
\frac {0}{\theta_2}\ln\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right)=
\ln\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2}\right)
$$

Why is this the incorrect way, and what is the correct one to solve KL(Q,P)?

Comment: Note that I could remove the indicator functions because $\theta_1 < \theta_2$, therefore, the $\frac{\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}}{\mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]}}$ was not a problem. If you want $KL(Q,P)$, you will get
$$
\int\frac{1}{\theta_2} \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]} 
\ln(\frac{\theta_1 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_2]} } {\theta_2 \mathbb I_{[0,\theta_1]}})
$$
Note then that if $\theta_2>x>\theta_1$, the indicator function in the logarithm will divide by zero in the denominator.